# eclipse and websphere 8.0 - cannot change the context root

Tags: websphere-8

I have the IBM plugin for eclipse that allows me to develop on websphere 8.0 servers.  I'm using eclipse (Juno Build).

Normally, in the project explorer, I can change the context root of an application simply by right-clicking >> properties >> Web Project Settings >> and setting the context root right there.  I can literally set that context root to anything, and it doesn't change anything about it.  When I check the admin console, it displays as being 'AppName', rather than anything I've set in the web project settings.  That and I'm unable to change it right there in the console, since the only button I can click is "cancel".  All the text fields are there for me to change it, but there's no save button anywhere...

Has anyone else had this issue?  What did you do to fix it, if at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 places you can set a `Context Root` in WebSphere.

The first is in the module definition inside the `application.xml` file of the EAR (That file is not mandatory in WAS 8 but it is possible to use it)

The second is in the `ibm-web-ext.xml` file inside the WAR.

Is it important to keep in mind the `application.xml` settings override the `ibm-web-ext.xml` settings.

When you set the context root in the UI it is setting the `ibm-web-ext.xml` file, if you got another definition in `application.xml` you will see no change, as you experiencing.

My suggestion is, if you are using `application.xml` always set the context root there.

Comment: That did it.  Sorry to get back so late... was making my rounds, and realized I forgot to mark this as my solution.  Thank you for your help :)